# Is there a way I can change any of the files shown here to deploy with webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, web, webpack

What's coming? (1) Short background. (2) Question. (3) Detail (short; file listings just long enough to show relevant information). (4) Question again.

**Short background**: I want to deploy my web site using `webpack`. webpack is looking for style-loader and css-loader in the wrong directories, so my builds aren't completing.

### Question

Is there a way I can change any of the files shown here to deploy with webpack?

### Detail

**environment**

Windows 10 Home -64, up-to-date/ Toshiba Satellite with AMD A6

Node v6.2.0/ webpack v1.13.2

**relevant files and directory structure**

```
C:\Dev\example\example.js
C:\Dev\example\bluebird.js
C:\Dev\example\jquery.js
C:\Dev\example\img\image1.jpg
C:\Dev\example\img\image2.jpg
C:\Dev\example\img\svg1.svg
C:\Dev\example\built\package.json
C:\Dev\example\built\webpack.config.js
C:\Dev\example\built\index1.html
C:\Dev\example\built\index2.html
C:\Dev\example\built\example.bundle.js
C:\Dev\example\built\[hash1].jpg
C:\Dev\example\built\[hash2].jpg
C:\Dev\example\built\[hash3].svg
C:\Dev\node-modules\webpack
C:\Dev\node-modules\css-loader
C:\Dev\node-modules\file-loader
C:\Dev\node-modules\html-loader
C:\Dev\node-modules\style-loader
C:\Dev\node-modules\uglify-js
C:\Dev\node-modules\url-loader
```

**C:\Dev\example\built\package.json**

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "example",
  "main": "example.bundle.js",
  "author": "Bald Eagle"
}
```

**call to webpack**: I call webpack at the command prompt from `C:\Dev\example\built` with one line (two here for your convenience)

```
node C:\Dev\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js -p --display-reasons
    --display-error-details --display-modules --profile
```

**C:\Dev\example\built\webpack.config.js**

```
"use strict"
let path = require("path")
let webpack = require("webpack")
let preferEntry = true // for OccurrenceOrderPlugin
module.exports = {
    context: "C:/Dev/example/built",
    entry: [
        "./index1.html",
        "./../jquery.js",
        "./../bluebird.js",
        "./../example.css"
    ],
    output: {                                                          
        path: "C:/Dev/example/built",
        filename: "./example.bundle.js",
        publicPath: "http://www.example.com"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(?:gif|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
                loader: "file!url"
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "html"
            },
            {
                test: /\.png$/,
                loader: "url-loader?mimetype=image/png"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
        }   ],
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true}),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                'window.$': 'jquery',
    })  ]   },
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve("./index1.html"),
        modulesDirectories: ["node_modules", "built"],
        fallback: "C:/Dev"
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        fallback: "C:/Dev",
        modulesDirectories: ["node_modules"]
    }
}
```

**C:\Dev\example\built\index1.html**: My goal for this HTML file is to point webpack the right direction to collect all information for the web site into its example.bundle.js file. I shortened one long line (clip) and excluded irrelevant lines, including the entire `body`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="./../example.js"></script>
<link href="./../example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? (clip) type="text/css" />
<script src="./../jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./../bluebird.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**feedback from webpack**

It outputs routine information about building pieces of example.bundle.js (represented with `...`), except these: (I added any double asterisks **; I broke some long lines and indented the later parts of such lines.)

```
...
[9] ./../example.css 919 bytes {0} [built] [**2 errors**]
    single entry ./../example.css [0] multi main

WARNING in ./example.bundle.js from UglifyJs
...
Condition always false [C:/Dev/~/style-loader!
    C:/Dev/~/css-loader!**./../example.css:10,0**]
Dropping unreachable code [C:/Dev/~/style-loader!
    C:/Dev/~/css-loader!**./../example.css:12,0**]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable update
    [C:/Dev/~/style-loader!C:/Dev/~/css-loader!
    **./../example.css:7,0**]

**ERROR** in ./../example.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'
    ./../node_modules/css-loader/index.js in
    C:/Dev/example/built\..
resolve file
  **C:/Dev/example/built\node_modules\css-loader\index.js
    doesn't exist**
[plus more similarly inaccurate variants; it should be looking
    for C:\Dev\node_modules\css-loader\index.js; it's there]    
...    
**ERROR** in ./../example.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'
    ./../node_modules/style-loader/addStyles.js in
    C:/Dev/example/built\..
resolve file
  **C:/Dev/example/built\node_modules\style-loader\addStyles.js.webpack.js
    doesn't exist**
[plus more similarly inaccurate variants]
...
```

With the double asterisks, I wanted to highlight that webpack outputted that there'd be two errors and outputted the two errors. Also, I wanted to highlight the cited points of error in css. Those lines are below.

**C:\Dev\example\example.css**: I show only the first twelve lines because of the lines webpack cited as errors; I added line numbers.

```
 1  /* example web site
 2   * blah
 3   * blah
 4   * blah
 5   * blah
 6   * blah
 7   *
 8   * Version
 9   */
10
11  /* defaults */
12  body, div {
```

My conclusion: The points webpack cited are not points of error. Maybe the points cited apply to a minified version of the file. Or to some code.

**Problem when I point a browser to index1.html above**: All content and rendering are fine; JavaScript isn't enabled. (Consistent with not processing css correctly?)

**C:\Dev\example\built\index2.html**: My goal for this HTML file is to use the same webpack techniques I'll use in the index.html that will be on the web server. I changed this the same ways I changed index1.html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="./example.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? (clip) type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**Problem when I point a browser to index2.html immediately above**: All content shows (including the three images), but (1) JavaScript isn't enabled and (2) there's no effect from css (no colors or positioning, etc.) (Consistent with not processing css correctly?)

### Question

Is there a way I can change any of the files shown here to deploy with webpack?

Thanks for taking the time to read. Thanks in advance for any responses.

Need more detail? I'll provide it if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've set up your project in a very unusual style for Node.js development which makes your setup more complicated than it needs to be. I'm not sure if that is a hard requirement, but since you've not mentioned it to be required, I'm assuming you are allowed to change your directory structure.

#### Use local dependencies

In Node.js, all dependencies are installed separately for each project. It enables you to use different versions of a dependency while working on different projects without the need to switch these dependencies manually. You should put the `package.json` in the root folder of your project (I assume `C:\Dev\example` in your case) and then run `npm install webpack css-loader style-loader --save-dev`. [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) is the package manager for Node.js that comes pre-bundled with the executable so it should already be installed on your system. After running `npm install` you should see a `node_modules` folder which contains all these project-specific dependencies. You should not commit these dependencies to your version control system because they may contain platform-specific binaries that are not usable on different machines. Every developer in this project needs to run `npm install` first.

#### Configure your common commands under scripts

NPM provides the possibility to add common commands as [`scripts`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) to your `package.json`. This way, other developers (including "Future You") only need to remember `npm run some-script` instead of all the command-line options. One little known feature of NPM is, that it prepends `./node_modules/.bin` to your `$PATH` on runtime which means that inside `scripts` you can reference any executable installed in your *local* `node_modules` just as if it was installed globally. Thus you only need to write:

`"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --config ./path/to/webpack.config.js"
}`

and it will use your local webpack installation. As a side-note: It's best-practice to provide a `"start"` script. It can be called by just running `npm start`.

#### Your webpack config

Your webpack config looks ok, but I have some advice:

- You should separate between your development stuff and the actual build. Usually, the `webpack.config.js` is placed in the root of your project because then you just need to run `webpack` and webpack will look for a config in the current directory. Then, you should have a `src` or `app` folder which contains all the development files, including the index HTML files as you've mentioned. At last, you create a `build` folder which is completely wiped before a build. This way, your build does not contain any obsolete files.
- Do not use absolute paths in your webpack.config. It makes sharing your project a lot harder – including "Future You" that moves the project to another directory. Use the Node.js builtin path module and the special module variable `__dirname` to resolve absolute paths. You can also use `require.resolve` to use Node's resolving algorithm.
- Do not set the `context` and the `publicPath` option unless you know what you are doing. Given from the information you've provided, I doubt that these options are necessary here.
- Since you've installed all the dependencies locally, you should remove all the resolving options because it should work out-of-the-box now.
- Although it is permitted, you should not omit the `-loader` postfix in your loader configurations. It can lead to hard-to-understand errors when you have a `css` or `html` module in your `node_modules` just by coincidence.

#### The problem with index.html files

webpack is a JavaScript bundler. That's why you need to have a css- or an html-loader if you want to *include* HTML or CSS. These loaders transform HTML or CSS into a JavaScript module by transforming the text contents into strings that are exported. This has some nice advantages like [hot module replacement](http://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html) or [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules). But it also means that you can't use an HTML or CSS file as the only entry point to your website. Every HTML and CSS will eventually be translated to JavaScript. This trade-off is ok for single-page applications where you need JS anyway, but it is probably surprising for everyone who tries to use webpack on a static site.

Since you're not the first one with this problem, several solutions have already emerged. My recommendation is to use the [HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) in combination with the [Extract Text Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin).

The Extract Text Webpack Plugin can be used to extract static JS strings out of the bundle into a speparate file. This is exactly what you need to remove CSS from the JS bundle.

The HTML Webpack Plugin creates an index HTML file that includes all the generated JS and CSS files. Out of the box, it will just generate an HTML file with no contents (often referred to application shell which is typical for single-page applications). Since you already have content in your index HTML files, you need to configure your HTML files as templates. You'll need to add a plugin for each HTML file.

These plugins work pretty well, but this setup is already pretty complex. You should decide if you want to use webpack just for JS or also for HTML and CSS.

Comment: You're generous with your skilled time. Thanks. I've read most every question here about webpack without finding my answer, so we're probably writing for future readers, too. On your advice, I'll (1) create local and global installations of packages I'm using here, (2) create a script in my project_root\package.json to call webpack and call it from there. (3) put my JS in project_root\app, (4) use resolve with __dirname for absolute paths, (5) delete webpack config.context and .publicPath, (6) remove the webpack.module.resolve section, (7) add -loader to webpack.module.loaders section, ...

Comment: (8) change webpack.module.entry to my JS, (9) use extractt-text-webpack-plugin and html-webpack-plugin as each of them recommend. I'm not sure I understand the reference to "HTML files as templates"; I'll dig to find it. Question: "decide if you want to use webpack just for JS or also for HTML and CSS": My objective is to create one bundle containing everything my readers need. They download the bundle, unzip it, and the website works. I gather that means the latter of your options, "also for HTML and CSS"?

Comment: In case your readers download a ZIP bundle anyway, I have to ask what your motivation was to use webpack. webpack's goal is to create performance-optimized bundles that are served via HTTP. In your case, many webpack features are not necessary.

Comment: Sure. Many features are not necessary for me. Now. But my readers don't yet "download the bundle, unzip it, and the website works." And I don't want them to be aware of it. `webpack` is one means of achieving that?

Comment: And, all my files look substantially different now (and simpler, more stream-lined), but I seem to be stuck in a cycle. `npm` sent me `extract-text-webpack-plugin` v1.0.1.That plugin reports `loader is used without the corresponding plugin, refer to https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin for the usage example`. That URL is v2-oriented, with a link to a v1 page, whose syntax I'm using. Known solution there?

Comment: I'm in a new place. I couldn't get `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to work, so I tried going with just `"style-loader!css-loader"`. Initially it wasn't working. I don't know what changed or how long it'll hold, but it's working, now. Another problem has popped up, but I'm getting close to a full solution. I plan to post the result.